# MIUI 12.01 System Update had changed My App to Night Mode.How to disable Night Mode?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In Application class I have added:

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Why is it not working ?

Comment: I've made minor changes to your post, I made your question actually ask a question and then some minor changes to formatting, feel free to change them if you're not happy with them, but I think it's a useful Q&A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

in Apptheme

```
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Not really a solution if you still want to use "forceDarkAllowed".